# Find values missing on one table which are present on another based on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been struggling with this for hours.

I have two tables: the first has attendance records, with a row id, client id, service date and number of units from 0 to 16. The second table has client responses with a row id, client id, service date and many other fields.

Here's the question: how do I find clients missing on the second table which have more than 0 units on the first table for a specific date? Please note that the only unique fields are the row ids.

After hours, I came up with this, which kind of works, but for some reason returns an empty result set for date ranges bigger than 20 days:

```
SELECT `caseload`.* FROM `caseload` WHERE `caseload`.`client_id` NOT IN
(
    SELECT  `caseload`.`client_id` FROM `caseload`
    JOIN    `form_psr`
    ON      `caseload`.`client_id` = `form_psr`.`client_id`
    AND     `caseload`.`date` = `form_psr`.`service_date`
    WHERE   `caseload`.`date` >= '2019-07-01' AND `caseload`.`date` <= '2019-07-31'
)
HAVING `date` >= '2019-07-01' AND `date` <= '2019-07-31'
AND `units` > 0
```

This sqlfiddle has some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a4be2/49

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select cl.*
from caseload c 
where c.units <= 16 and
      c.service_date >= '2019-07-01' and
      c.service_date <  '2019-08-01' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from form_psr as fp 
                  where c.client_id = fp.client_id 
                 );
```

Note that I also changed the date comparisons.  This version works both for dates and date/time values.  In general, `between` can have unexpected behavior with date/time values, so I recommend using this unambiguous construct.

I also assume that the number of units is never negative.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. I need the units to be bigger than 0. I changed the query to units > 0 and didn't return anything.

Comment: Hi Gordon! After trying your solution again, I realized that it was just missing another constraint on the second select clause, so I added c.service_date = fp.service_date and changed the units to > 0 and now it works! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi use left join to determine the users that are in caseload but not in form_psr and use were a clause to filter the date and number of units.

```
    select
       * 
    from
       caseload as c 
       left join
          form_psr as fp 
          on c.client_id = fp.client_id 
    where
       fp.client_id is null 
       and
       c.units > 0 
       and 
       c.service_date between '2019-07-01' AND  '2019-07-31'
```

Comment: Thanks Amila. But the problem is that the user might exist on the form_psr table, just for any other date. That's why I said that the only unique fields are the row ids. I just tried it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon's solution I was able to fix my issue with only a couple of modifications. I accepted his solution but I'm posting exactly what I ended up with to clarify. Here's the final query:

```
select *
from caseload c 
where c.units > 0 and
      c.service_date >= '2019-07-01' and
      c.service_date <= '2019-08-01' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from form_psr as fp 
                  where c.client_id = fp.client_id 
                  and c.service_date = fp.service_date
                 );
```